# Tables at the end of the document with Appendix

Tags: tables

I have a `LaTeX` document that contains sections and appendices. Some sections and appendices discuss tables. **The tables should be listed at the end of the document** **(they cannot be listed within each corresponding section)**. I would like the tables referred to in the sections to be numbered Table 1, Table 2, Table 3, etc. Instead, the tables referred to in the appendices should be numbered Table A.1, Table A.2, ... (if referred to in Appendix A), Table B.1, Table B.2, ... (if referred to in Appendix B),  etc.

As suggested in the comments, I've tried to use `endfloat` but it does not seem to work, perhaps I'm not implementing it in the correct way.

This is a working example:

```
 \documentclass[12 pt,a4paper, oneside, openany, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[inner=1in,outer=1in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage[nomarkers, nolists]{endfloat}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
Talk about Table \ref{tab1}. This Table should be numbered 1.
 \begin{table}  
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }
\hline
Examples     &  [1]                 &[2]                          &[3]                    &[4]                     & [5]               &[6]                   \\
\hline
a                   &  a   & a          &                       &                        &                     &                        \\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Blah.}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\section{Section 2}
Talk about Table \ref{tab2}. This Table should be numbered 2.
 \begin{table}  
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }
\hline
Examples     &  [1]                 &[2]                          &[3]                    &[4]                     & [5]               &[6]                   \\
\hline
a                   &  a   & a          &                       &                        &                     &                        \\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Blah.}
\label{tab2}
\end{table}

\begin{appendix}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\section{Appendix A}
\section{Appendix B}
Talk about Table \ref{tabB1}. This Table should be numbered B.1.
 \begin{table} 
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }
\hline
Examples     &  [1]                 &[2]                          &[3]                    &[4]                     & [5]               &[6]                   \\
\hline
a                   &  a   & a          &                       &                        &                     &                        \\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Blah.}
\label{tabB1}
\end{table}

\end{appendix}
```

The numbering should be Table 1, Table 2, Table B.1.

Comment: why `\input epsf` ???? (latex has had a standard graphics package for  almost 30 years, is this document older than that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've deleted that.

Comment: @Teepeemm That is indeed my problem! The tables SHOULD be listed after the appendices, it is a format required by a journal for publication. The tables cannot be listed within each corresponding section. However, their numbering should be AS IF they were listed within each corresponding section.

Comment: you can put the tables in the natural place so they pick up the appendix number but use `endfloat` or similar package so they appear at the end

Comment: @DavidCarlisle endfloat does not seem to work (see my example with endfloat). They all pick up the appendix number.

Comment: I looks like the `endfloat` packge cannot handle a midstream switch in the numbering style of `table` and `figure` floats.

Comment: Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: You can change the numbering style midstream with: `\addtodelayedfloat{table}{\counterwithin{table}{section}}` instead of just `\counterwithin{table}{section}`

Comment: If I do that, the third table is numbered B.3 instead of B.1

Answer (score 1):

The thing to remember is that all the code inside the table environment will be executed at the end of the document.  The solution is to save `\thetable` as formatted outside the table environment using `\pretable`, then copy them when tables are run.

Note, if you have two captions in one table, you will need two `\pretable`s, etc.

```
\documentclass[12 pt,a4paper, oneside, openany, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[inner=1in,outer=1in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage[nomarkers, nolists]{endfloat}

\newcounter{tablenumber}% does not reset to 0
\newcommand{\pretable}{\stepcounter{tablenumber}\stepcounter{table}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname TABLE\arabic{tablenumber}\endcsname{\thetable}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
Talk about Table \ref{tab1}. This Table should be numbered 1.
\pretable
 \begin{table}  
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }
\hline
Examples     &  [1]                 &[2]                          &[3]                    &[4]                     & [5]               &[6]                   \\
\hline
a                   &  a   & a          &                       &                        &                     &                        \\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Blah.}
\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\section{Section 2}
Talk about Table \ref{tab2}. This Table should be numbered 2.
\pretable
 \begin{table}  
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }
\hline
Examples     &  [1]                 &[2]                          &[3]                    &[4]                     & [5]               &[6]                   \\
\hline
a                   &  a   & a          &                       &                        &                     &                        \\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Blah.}
\label{tab2}
\end{table}

\begin{appendix}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\section{Appendix A}
\section{Appendix B}
Talk about Table \ref{tabB1}. This Table should be numbered B.1.
\pretable
 \begin{table} 
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c }
\hline
Examples     &  [1]                 &[2]                          &[3]                    &[4]                     & [5]               &[6]                   \\
\hline
a                   &  a   & a          &                       &                        &                     &                        \\
\hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{Blah.}
\label{tabB1}
\end{table}

\end{appendix}
\setcounter{table}{0}%
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\csname TABLE\arabic{table}\endcsname}%
\end{document}
```